# Animate content in a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, list

I want to make it so that when I hover over one of the items in a list, it moves that element. 
Here is my HTML code for the list:

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="test"><a href="http://choughsttc.com/">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://choughsttc.com/">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://choughsttc.com/">About us</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://choughsttc.com/">Venue</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://choughsttc.com/">Affiliations</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://choughsttc.com/">Players & Officers</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://choughsttc.com/">Fixtures & Results</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://choughsttc.com/">Coaching</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://choughsttc.com/">Contact us</a></li>
</ul>
```

And here is my Jquery code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('').mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).animate({ left: '+=100px' });
      });

      $('').mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).animate({ left: '-=100px' });
      });
    });
```

Basically, my question is what goes in the quote marks in the JQuery functions?

Comment: Uhm, how about `.nav li` ?

Comment: I forgot to say, <ul class nav> is inside <div class sidebar1>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [on](https://api.jquery.com/on/) event

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.nav').on({
         mouseenter : function(){
            $(this).animate({left: '+=100px'});
         },
        mouseleave : function(){
            $(this).animate({left: '-=100px'});
         }
     }, 'li');
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
    {
    $('.nav li').mouseenter(function()
    {
        $(this).animate({left: '+=100px'});
    });

    $('.nav li').mouseleave(function()
    {
        $(this).animate({left: '-=100px'});
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$('.nav li')` to target list items of your `nav`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.nav li').mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            left: '+=100px'
        });
    });

    $('.nav li').mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            left: '-=100px'
        });
    });
});
```

Also, you need to set `position: relative` for your list items, so the `left` value can work:

```
.nav li {
    position: relative;
}
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DhELW/)**

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider the `.on` and event map approach.

```
$('.nav').on({
  mouseenter : function(){
    $(this).animate({left: '+=100px'});
  },
  mouseleave : function(){
    $(this).animate({left: '-=100px'});
  }
}, 'li');
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML Code:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="http://choughsttc.com/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Venue</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Affiliations</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Players & Officers</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Fixtures & Results</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Coaching</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.nav li').mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            left: '+=100px'
        });
    });

    $('.nav li').mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).animate({
             left: '-=100px'
        });
    });
});
```

A little CSS tweek to make the list hover animation work:

```
.nav {
   padding: 20px 0 0 20px;
}
.nav li {
   position: relative;
}
```

Check the demo at: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/utpalpaul/Fcw86/3/)